# Highlighted header not readable in emacs rst-mode

Tags: emacs, highlight, highlighting, restructuredtext

Emacs has a built-in `rst-mode`, but the header highlight literally makes it unreadable. Is there some quick fix for this?

[image: screenshot]

The screenshot above is produced on a Mac OS X using [iTerm2](http://iterm2.com/), with `emacs -Q` command (which means no customized `.emacs` will be used). I am using emacs version 24.4.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find out the name of a face, put your point on it and call
`describe-face`. This tells you that it is `rst-level-1`. Looking at
the value, you probably want to change 'Background'.

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(rst-level-1 ((t (:background "white")))))
```

See the [face customization
node](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Face-Customization.html) in the manual for more details.

Comment: Thanks so much, @Kyle. That's exactly what I am looking for. One more question, how can I set the background color of `rst-level-1` to "the same background color as the main text"? Because the desired background is sometimes "white" (when using emacs UI) and sometimes "black" (when using emacs in command line). Thanks!

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer, which is to set `(custom-set-faces
 '(rst-level-1 ((t (:background 'default)))))`. Thanks again for your help.